# IBM cloud storage, getting error while creating bucket with aws sdk

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, cloud-storage

I am getting below error while trying to access ibm cloud storage

> Container storage location with specified provisioning code not available (Service: Amazon > Status Code: 400.

Please see the snippet of code of i am using to create a bucket in ibm cloud storage using aws s3 client sdk.

```
    String accessKey = (ACCESS_KEY);
    String secretKey = (SECRET_KEY);
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,
            secretKey);
    AmazonS3Client s3service = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    s3service.setEndpoint(END_POINT);
    s3service.createBucket("samplebucket");
```

The above code is working only for us-south end point(s3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud)

As per the ibm official docs[0] there are the other endpoints for different regions, but none of them is working using above code.

[0]- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage-infrastructure?topic=cloud-object-storage-infrastructure-select-regions-and-endpoints

Comment: The official docs are here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-endpoints. Please add what exactly you tried, all parameters except your credentials.

Comment: This snippet of code is not working for me : `String accessKey = (ACCESS_KEY);
    String secretKey = (SECRET_KEY);
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,
            secretKey);
    AmazonS3Client s3service = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    s3service.setEndpoint("https://s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud");
    s3service.createBucket("samplebucket");`

Answer (score 0):

I am taking an example of how to use Java SDK with region/location specified

```
String location = "us"; 
AmazonS3 cosClient = createClient(apiKey, serviceInstanceId, endpointUrl, location);
```

The `createClient` static method looks like this

```
 public static AmazonS3 createClient(String apiKey, String serviceInstanceId, String endpointUrl, String location)
        {
            AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicIBMOAuthCredentials(apiKey, serviceInstanceId);
            ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration()
                    .withRequestTimeout(5000)
                    .withTcpKeepAlive(true);

            return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(endpointUrl, location))
                    .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                    .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig)
                    .build();
        }
```

As per the [documentation here](https://ibm.github.io/ibm-cos-sdk-java/com/ibm/cloud/objectstorage/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#withRegion-java.lang.String-), `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` has an option to pass the region using `withRegion`.

Check the complete COS Java SDK [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage/libraries?topic=cloud-object-storage-java#java-examples)

**Updated:**

If you see the Java example in the [COS documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage/libraries?topic=cloud-object-storage-java#java-examples), there is something called *Storage class*.

> storageClass is a valid provisioning code that corresponds to the
> endpoint value. This is then used as the S3 API LocationConstraint
> variable.

To create a bucket with a different storage class programmatically, it is necessary to specify a LocationConstraint that corresponds with the endpoint used.

You can find the valid provisioning codes for LocationConstraint in the [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-classes#classes-locationconstraint)

**Further read - API documentation:**

- [Create a bucket](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage/api-reference?topic=cloud-object-storage-compatibility-api-bucket-operations#compatibility-api-storage-class)
- [Create bucket configuration](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cos/cos-compatibility#create-a-bucket)

Comment: Thanks Vidyasage, but what my snippet of code is working for one endpoint and not for others. I have taken ibm endpoints from their documentation itself

Comment: Do you see any error code along with the status code? Can you provide the complete error?

Comment: @Neeraj Updated my answer with LocationConstraint information

Comment: @vidyasage i want to create bucket in same region as the the client configured endpoint. If you see  `AmazonS3Client class(https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-java/blob/master/ibm-cos-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/ibm/cloud/objectstorage/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java) ` which has createBucket functions and does not require any storage class to specify. this particular class functions are not working.

Comment: Just to summarise my query:

This particular class function[0] is not working for me endpoints (except us-south endpoint)

[0] - https://ibm.github.io/ibm-cos-sdk-java/com/ibm/cloud/objectstorage/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#createBucket-java.lang.String-